# Force to import Excel columns in original format

Tags: import, excel

Is it possible to import data from Excel file so that imported values keeps their original format? I mean if cell formatted in Excel as text import it as String, if cell is integer, than import it as integer. If it is not possible I would like be able at least force to import columns in specific format. For example columns 1,2 I import as integers and 3,4 as strings.

In my case the column with "ids" which is generally the string but could be also a string of digits interpreted by Mathematica as real number in last case. While I want "ids" always as string.

Comment: I think mathematica does not know how excel had cells formatted, so there is no way to do this automatically. You can of course apply `ToString` to the desired column.

Comment: If I apply ToString there is an extra point at the end of the string because Mathematica interpreted the value as real number. And I cannot apply Floor to the column because the are also string values. So I should iterate trough all imported values.

Comment: Try the documentation on SemanticImport

Answer (score 3):

One way is to save the Excel worksheet as "XML Table" and then `Import` this table in *Mathematica* as `"XML"` [with option `"IncludeNamespaces" -> "Unparsed"`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7853/280):

```
XMLData = Import["test.xml", "IncludeNamespaces" -> "Unparsed"]
```

The `XMLData` contains all the information about formatting of the worksheet. It can be analyzed and modified inside *Mathematica*, and further `Export`ed as Excel-compatible XML file:

```
Export["test-from MMa.xml", XMLData]
```

The exported file is recognized by Excel as its native format.