# ExcelLink: How to change cell properties like font family, size and borders?

Tags: color, interoperability, excel, format, excellink

I just purchased the Mathematica Link for Excel. I can't figure out how to change the cell properties in excel using ExcelLink package? Can someone please help.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tried the most recent version of ExcelLink, but with the previous versions it was not possible. If you wish to generate formatted Excel tables from *Mathematica*, one way is to generate XML files with specific header which Excel recognizes as its native XML format called "XML Table". In the following threads I discuss this method (although the complete solution wasn't developed):

- [How to export to Excel numbers as text fields from Mathematica?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11256618/590388)
- [Why does Export drop namespace prefixes in the exported XML file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7853/280)

Some other methods were suggested here:

- [How to write data from Mathematica to an existing formated Excel file?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/15786/280)

Answer (score 3):

If you can't do it with Excel Link you can with NETLink.  For example,

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
PutIntoExcel[data_List, cell_String, file_String] :=
 Module[{rows, cols, excel, workbook, worksheet, srcRange},
  {rows, cols} = Dimensions[data];
  NETBlock[
   InstallNET[];
   excel = CreateCOMObject["Excel.Application"];
   If[! NETObjectQ[excel], Return[$Failed],
    excel[Visible] = True;
    workbook = excel@Workbooks@Add[];
    worksheet = workbook@Worksheets@Item[1];
    srcRange = worksheet@Range[cell]@Resize[rows, cols];
    srcRange@Value = data;
    srcRange@Interior@Color = 13959039;
    (*OLE colours from http://www.endprod.com/colors/*)
    worksheet@Range[cell]@Resize[1, 2]@Font@Bold = True;
    worksheet@Range[cell]@Resize[1, 2]@Interior@Color = 61166;
    worksheet@Range[cell]@Offset[1, 0]@Resize[4, 1]@Font@Color = 255;
    (*Reset the numeric values to get the correct type*)
    worksheet@Range[cell]@Offset[1, 0]@Resize[4, 1]@NumberFormat = "0.000";
    worksheet@Range[cell]@Offset[1, 0]@Resize[4, 1]@Value =
      List /@ Rest[data[[All, 1]]];
    workbook@SaveAs[file];
    workbook@Close[False];
    excel@Quit[];
    ]];
  LoadNETType["System.GC"];
  GC`Collect[]];

data = {{"Year", "Cartoon"}, {1928, "Mickey Mouse"}, {1934,
   "Donald Duck"}, {1940, "Bugs Bunny"}, {1949, "Road Runner"}};
outputfile = "C:\\Temp\\demo.xlsx";
Quiet[DeleteFile[outputfile]];
PutIntoExcel[data, "E5", outputfile];

Print[Panel[TableForm[data, TableSpacing -> {2, 4}]]];
```

Excel produced:

[image]

Comment: With which version of Excel have you tested your solution? With Excel 2003 it fails :( ...

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov Tested on Office 2010. Try naming file demo.xls for earlier versions.

Comment: Thank you, after changing output file to `"D:\\Temp\\demo.xls"` it works!

Comment: What is the purpose of ``LoadNETType["System.GC"]; GC`Collect[]``?

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov It's [garbage collection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe0c2357(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @ChrisDegnen Hey you seem to know your way around `NETLink` and `Excel` can you help me with my question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/269392/how-to-pass-the-second-parameter-to-com-object-in-netlink) please.