# How to pass the second parameter to COM object in NETLink?

Tags: excel, .netlink

I am trying to add a copy after the active sheet.

I can add it before as follows (this question was asked [before](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1385086) but now I need the answer to make my workflow:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[]
excelObj=CreateCOMObject["Excel.Application"]
wb=excelObj@Workbooks@Open["~/example.xlsx"]
sheets=wb@Worksheets
sheets[1]@Copy[sheets[1]]
```

but I need to add it after which is the second parameter. How do I pass the active sheet as the second parameter? Tried the following without success:

```
sheets[1]@Copy[None(*what do I put here?*),sheets[1]]
```

Documentation for `NETLink` is so bad that it is missing very trivial things like these.

Also, what is the syntax for passing named parameters?

[Here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.copy) is the reference page for the Copy method.

Comment: Could you please provide a complete example of what you are trying to do? (I.e. include all the code needed to run the problematic command) Like this, it is very hard for people to try and help you, because they first have to guess how exactly you are doing things (also, copy and paste is way faster, so people are more likely to invest time to actually try to help you)

Comment: @LukasLang added the commands and reference to another question asked on the Wolfram Community.

Comment: I would have guessed that a simple `sheets[1]@Copy[Null,sheets[1]]` works (since `Null` is the default value of the `Before` argument), but for some reason it fails on my machine. One crazy alternative is to compile a dll on-the-fly to do the call for you, but so far I haven't managed to get the correct dll compiled from within Mathematica

Comment: I think it's `Type.Missing` based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27005582/11965951) (haven't tested it).

Comment: @BenIzd how do you get access to this type in `NETLink`?

Comment: @user13892 First `LoadNETType["System.Type"]` then ```Type`Missing```.

Comment: @BenIzd thank you it works! If you want to provide it as an answer, I will accept it. You deserve it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Microsoft noted on the [`Type.Missing`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.missing?view=net-6.0) Page:

> The following code example shows the use of the Missing field to invoke a method with its default arguments.

To use this in Mathematica, first load the type:

```
LoadNETType["System.Type"]
```

Then use `` Type`Missing `` as the missing argument.