# Excel file reference disappears after `Import`; how to avoid this?

Tags: excel

**EDIT**

An excel file reference in a formula like `=[source.xlsx]Sheet1!A1` will be replaced by `[1]Sheet1!A1` after 'Import'.

How do I avoid this or, alternatively, how do I recover the original file name that this Excel cell references to?

**END EDIT**

A very simple example that replicates this behavior is set up by creating an excel file `source.xlsx` with the `A1` cell value set to `5`.

```
Export["source.xlsx", {{5}}];
```

I refer to this cell value from `reference.xlsx`.

```
Export["reference.xlsx", {{"=[source.xlsx]Sheet1!A1"}}];
```

Now when I import the `reference.xlsx` file, I do not get anything back as a formula because the cell value has not been evaluated by Excel.

```
Import["reference.xlsx"]
Import["reference.xlsx", "Formulas"]

(* Out[..]= {{{"=[source.xlsx]Sheet1!A1"}}}*)
(* Out[..]= {{{}}}*)
```

If I open `reference.xlsx` with excel and evaluate the cell and save, I arrive at the actual real life situation where I would like to find the file reference.

However the file reference in the formula `=[source.xlsx]Sheet1!A1` has been replaced by `[1]Sheet1!A1`

```
Import["reference.xlsx"]
Import["reference.xlsx", "Formulas"]

(* Out[..]= {{{5.}}}*)
(* {{"[1]Sheet1!A1"}}}*)
```

How can I find the original file reference that was replaced by `[1]`?

Comment: I managed to navigate the problem away by identifying where the unwanted replacement happens and creating a new excelsheet with the excel function `FORMULATEXT referring to the original cell, and then usiong that result to revert the replacement. Far from ideal though ... and hence keenly interested in real solutions.

Comment: Have you tried saving your Excel file as "XML Table"? Excel recognizes such files as its native file format, they are automatically opened in Excel when you double-click them in the Windows Explorer. More importantly, Excel works with such files exactly as with its native XLSX files. *Mathematica* has much higher flexibility when [importing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/9573/280) such files.